# Why is Facebook Login in iOS, Android appearing to work yet it's flagged in the FB Console as "not successful"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I have hit a road block and am asking for direction on how to resolve the problem Facebook Developer Console is giving me.What to check, where to look, or what to try to resolve this error. The error message is:

> Facebook Login has not been used successfully on your app in the past
>   30 days. Please test Facebook Login with your app prior to submitting
>   for review. Be sure to test the entire login flow, starting with the
>   TOS agreement (this may require uninstalling and reinstalling your
>   app). We will remove your app from the App Center if we determine that
>   you have not integrated Facebook Login correctly.

The appearance of this error, 30 days after I made the app public, was a complete surprise. Login seemed to have been working fine for my test accounts. The login callback is being called because I use it to update my interface and display a tournament table. I could log in, retrieve scores for friends who had played my game, and send challenges and post stories to my feed. So, how is it not working?

My attempts to resolve have been:

- Review FB Console for any insights. There are no "errors" reported,
  several hundred API requests, three active users. **Under Insights > Login I do see logins for the Web and Android versions, but not iOS.**
- Tested app on iPad and Galaxy Tab 4. Login button brings up dialog
  with a button in iOS to use my existing FB identity, and then
  correctly loads my previous game score. The same occurs on Android,
  bringing up my latest high score, name and photo. I successfully
  posted an update to my wall on iPad. Uninstalled and re-installed the
  app several times. Tested on a real friend's device and could post to
  his wall from within the game.
- Re-checked my integration script and log files.
- Re-read FB Unity SDK integration guide, sample project code, and
  reference pages for FB.Init, FB.Login, FB.API, FB.Feed
- Searched Google and StackOverflow. Did not find any answer to this
  question.

I have followed the Facebook Unity Games Tutorial and used code from the Friend Smash integration example projects. My app is published and set to allow public access. I went through testing by creating Facebook test users and verifying they showed up properly in the game, along with the simulated test user friends.

I do see a problem in that my Facebook friend, who can log in to my game with FB, does not get his score saved. After he  logs in, he sees my tournament page, my photo, name and current score come up, his photo, name and zero score come up.   When I log in to my game on my device, I only see my photo, name and current score. As a Facebook friend of mine, I expect to see him show up, but he doesn't.   This behavior did not occur with my test users created in the console prior to switching to public mode. I do not know if that is related to the error Facebook Console is displaying.

***Update: I expect I will be able to write scores if I submit my game to Facebook for review to activate the publish_actions permission. However, the fact that the error they give me states they may remove my game if they determine FB Login is not correctly implemented gives me pause. I would like to get rid of the above error first.***

I am using Facebook Unity SDK 5.1. I tried to update my project to use the 6.0 version, but was not successful because it is not clear how I need to adjust code. The Facebook tutorial and Unity Games Tutorial are said to only work with version 5.1.  The upgrading from 1.0 to 2.0 API documentation only addresses Web, iOS and Android SDKs, and not the Unity SDK. So API 5.1 is what I am using.

Other pertinent factors:

• My Unity canvas build is hosted on Parse but I have not implemented the Parse APIs.

• App ID in Unity matches FB console

• iOS Bundle ID in Unity matches FB Console

• Google Play Package Name is the same as the iOS bundle ID

• I created the Android key hash using this method:

```
# keytool -exportcert -alias myaliasname -keystore AndroidApps.keystore  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

• Android class name in FB console = com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity

• Single Sign On is set to Yes for iOS and Android; Deep linking is set to Off for both

• iPad Store ID has correct numeric ID; iPhone is blank because my app is iPad only

• "Native or Desktop App" is set to No

• Client OAuth Login is set to On

• "App Secret Proof", "Embedded Browser OAuth Login", "2 Factor Authentication" are each set to Off

• "Valid OAuth Redirect URLs" is blank

• "Stream Post URL Security" is set to Off

• "Enhanced Auth Dialog" is Off

• The queryString in the Friend Smash completed project for Unity used /2.0 to query scores. I'm using the SDK version 5.1 the example project was intended to run under, so I am using /2.0 to query scores in my game.

Here is all my Facebook code, minus the variable declarations and comments.

/

```
**
 * Based on MainMenu.cs in Friend Smash example for Facebook SDK 5.1
 *
 * Notable differences:
 * 
 * Message receiver onBragClicked is called from the UIButton.
 * If the player is logged in to FB, it brags. 
 * If not, it sets a variable doAfterLogin = 1, calls FB.Login, and the erceiver OnLoggedIn
 * called onBragClicked again, and this time since we are logged in, it brags
 *
 * doAfterLogin =2 is set in another script to refresh the tournament UI after login from that panel's login button.
 */


public class FBSingleton : MonoBehaviour
{

#region init and login

    void Awake()
    {
        // allow only one instance of the Main Menu
        if (instance != null && instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = this;

        // Initialize FB SDK
        enabled = false;
        FB.Init(SetInit, OnHideUnity);
    }


    private void SetInit()
    {
        enabled = true; // "enabled" is a property inherited from MonoBehaviour
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            OnLoggedIn();
            loadingState = LoadingState.WAITING_FOR_INITIAL_PLAYER_DATA;
        }
        else
        {
            loadingState = LoadingState.DONE;
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown)
        {
            // Tell scripts to pause their own way. 
            System.Object[] objects = FindObjectsOfType (typeof(GameObject));
            foreach (GameObject go in objects) {
                go.SendMessage ("OnPauseGame", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }

            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // start the game back up - we're getting focus again
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            System.Object[] objects = FindObjectsOfType (typeof(GameObject));
            foreach (GameObject go in objects) {
                go.SendMessage ("OnResumeGame", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }

    void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Util.LogError("LoginCallback: " + result.Error);
        }

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            OnLoggedIn();
        }
    }
    string meQueryString = "/v2.0/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id,picture.width(128).height(128)),invitable_friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id,picture.width(128).height(128))";


    void OnLoggedIn()
    {
        // Reqest player info and profile picture
        FB.API(meQueryString, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);
        LoadPictureAPI(Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128),MyPictureCallback);

        // Load high scores
        QueryScores();

        // Do something special after login
        if (doAfterLogin == 1) {
            doAfterLogin = 0;

            onBragClicked();
        } else if (doAfterLogin == 2) { // Set in MenuController.cs FBLoginTournamentPressed method
            doAfterLogin = 0;

            var menuController = GameObject.FindWithTag("MenuController");
            if (menuController) {
                menuController.SendMessage ("MMFacebookChallengeLoginSucceeded");
            } else { Util.LogError ("Failed to find menuController"); }
        }

    }


    void APICallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Util.LogError("APICallback: " + result.Error);
            // Let's just try again
            FB.API(meQueryString, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);
            return;
        }

        profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);
        GameStateManager.Username = profile["first_name"];
        friends = Util.DeserializeJSONFriends(result.Text);
        checkIfUserDataReady();
    }

    void MyPictureCallback(Texture texture)
    {
        if (texture ==  null)
        {
            // Let's just try again
            LoadPictureAPI(Util.GetPictureURL("me", 128, 128),MyPictureCallback);
            return;
        }

        GameStateManager.UserTexture = texture;
        haveUserPicture = true;
        checkIfUserDataReady();
    }

#endregion

#region Tournament and Scores

    private void QueryScores()
    {
        FB.API("/app/scores?fields=score,user.limit(20)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, ScoresCallback);
    }


    private int getScoreFromEntry(object obj)
    {
        Dictionary<string,object> entry = (Dictionary<string,object>) obj;
        return Convert.ToInt32(entry["score"]);
    }

    void ScoresCallback(FBResult result) 
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Util.LogError("ScoresCallback: " + result.Error);
            return;
        }

        scores = new List<object>();
        List<object> scoresList = Util.DeserializeScores(result.Text);

        foreach(object score in scoresList) 
        {
            var entry = (Dictionary<string,object>) score;
            var user = (Dictionary<string,object>) entry["user"];

            string userId = (string)user["id"];

            if (string.Equals(userId,FB.UserId))
            {
                // This entry is the current player
                int playerHighScore = getScoreFromEntry(entry);
                highScore = playerHighScore;

                if (playerHighScore < GameStateManager.Score)
                {
                    playerHighScore = GameStateManager.Score;
                    highScore = playerHighScore;
                }

                entry["score"] = playerHighScore.ToString();
                GameStateManager.HighScore = playerHighScore;
            }

            scores.Add(entry);
            if (!friendImages.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                // We don't have this players image yet, request it now
                LoadPictureAPI(Util.GetPictureURL(userId, 128, 128),pictureTexture =>
                               {
                    if (pictureTexture != null)
                    {
                        friendImages.Add(userId, pictureTexture);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // Now sort the entries based on score
        scores.Sort(delegate(object firstObj,
                             object secondObj)
                    {
            return -getScoreFromEntry(firstObj).CompareTo(getScoreFromEntry(secondObj));
        }
        );
    }


    public void RemoveHighScoreMessages () 
    {
        GameObject[] hiScores = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("NGUIHiScoreEntry");
        foreach(GameObject hiScore in hiScores)
        {
            Destroy(hiScore);
        }

    }


    public void DisplayHighScoreMessages() 
    {
        if(scores != null)
        {
            var menuController1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("MenuController");
            if (menuController1 != null) {
                menuController1.SendMessage ("MMFBHideTournamentText");
            }

            // Remove previously created entries
            RemoveHighScoreMessages();

            // table game object
            var highScoresPanel = GameObject.FindWithTag("highScoresGrid"); // for a scrolling grid
            var menuController = GameObject.FindWithTag("MenuController");

            var x = 0;
            foreach(object scoreEntry in scores) 
            {
                Dictionary<string,object> entry = (Dictionary<string,object>) scoreEntry;
                Dictionary<string,object> user = (Dictionary<string,object>) entry["user"];

                string name     = ((string) user["name"]).Split(new char[]{' '})[0] + "\n";
                string score     = entry["score"] + "";

                var tableEntry = NGUITools.AddChild(highScoresPanel, HighScoreEntryPrefab);

                var entryPosition = tableEntry.transform.Find("Position");
                var tableEntryPosition = entryPosition.GetComponent<UILabel>();
                tableEntryPosition.text = (x+1)+".";

                var entryNameObject = tableEntry.transform.Find("Name");
                var tableEntryName = entryNameObject.GetComponent<UILabel>();
                tableEntryName.text = name;

                var entryScoreObject = tableEntry.transform.Find("Score");
                var tableEntryScore = entryScoreObject.GetComponent<UILabel>();
                tableEntryScore.text = score;

                Texture picture;
                if (friendImages.TryGetValue((string) user["id"], out picture)) 
                {
                    var entryPhotoObject = tableEntry.transform.Find("Photo");
                    var tableEntryPhoto = entryPhotoObject.GetComponent<UITexture>();
                    tableEntryPhoto.mainTexture = picture;
                }

                x++;
                if (x > 29) { // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (highScoresPanel) highScoresPanel.GetComponent<UIGrid>().Reposition();
        } else {
            // invite friends screen since no friends available
            var menuController = GameObject.FindWithTag("MenuController");
            if (menuController != null) {
                menuController.SendMessage ("MMFBChallengeSwapLogin");
            }
        }
    }


    public void writeFBScore(int score)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            var queryScore = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            queryScore["score"] = score.ToString();
            FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate(FBResult r) { Util.Log("writeFBScore Result: " + r.Text); }, queryScore);
        }

    }

#endregion


#region UI button message receivers

    public void FBLoginPressed ()  // Message receiver for login button
    {
        if (! FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            FB.Login("public_profile,user_friends,email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
        }
    }

    public void FBChallengeLoginPressed ()  // message receiver for tournament panel login button
    {
        if (! FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            FB.Login("public_profile,user_friends,email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
        }
    }


    public void onBragClicked()
    {
        // Access global varaibles in JavaScript game state script
        GameObject Globals = GameObject.Find("/Globals");
        if (Globals != null) {
            Glob gs  = Globals.GetComponent(typeof(Glob)) as Glob;
        } else {
            Util.LogError ("onBragClicked globals object is null");
        }

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            FB.Feed(
                linkCaption: "I just scored " + Glob.score.ToString() + " in " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Glob.timerMin, Glob.timerSec) + "! Can you beat it?",
                picture: "http://www.myhost.com/timeline.jpg",
                linkName: "Completed Level " + Glob.puzzle.ToString() + "!",
                link: "http://apps.facebook.com/" + FB.AppId + "/?challenge_brag=" + (FB.IsLoggedIn ? FB.UserId : "guest")
                );
        } else {
            doAfterLogin = 1; // brag after log in
            FB.Login("public_profile,user_friends,email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
        }
    }


    public void onChallengeClicked()
    {
        Util.Log("onChallengeClicked");
        if (GameStateManager.Score != 0 && GameStateManager.FriendID != null)
        {
            string[] recipient = { GameStateManager.FriendID };
            FB.AppRequest(
                message: "I just beat your " + GameStateManager.Score.ToString() + "! Can you beat it?",
                to: recipient,
                filters : "",
                excludeIds : null,
                maxRecipients : null,
                data: "{\"challenge_score\":" + GameStateManager.Score.ToString() + "}",
                title: "Puzzle Challenge!",
                callback:appRequestCallback
                );
        }
        else
        {
            FB.AppRequest(
                to: null,
                filters : "",
                excludeIds : null,
                message: "Check it out.",
                title: "Play with me!",
                callback:appRequestCallback
                );
        }
    }

#endregion

    private void appRequestCallback (FBResult result)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            object obj = 0;
            if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("cancelled", out obj))
            {
                Util.Log("Request cancelled");
            }
            else if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("request", out obj))
            {
                Util.Log("Request sent");
            }
        }
    }

    void checkIfUserDataReady()
    {
        if (haveUserPicture && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GameStateManager.Username))
        {
            loadingState = LoadingState.DONE;
        }
    }


    public static void FriendPictureCallback(Texture texture)
    {
        GameStateManager.FriendTexture = texture;
    }

    delegate void LoadPictureCallback (Texture texture);


    IEnumerator LoadPictureEnumerator(string url, LoadPictureCallback callback)    
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        callback(www.texture);
    }
    void LoadPictureAPI (string url, LoadPictureCallback callback)
    {
        FB.API(url,Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,result =>
               {
            if (result.Error != null)
            {
                Util.LogError(result.Error);
                return;
            }

            var imageUrl = Util.DeserializePictureURLString(result.Text);

            StartCoroutine(LoadPictureEnumerator(imageUrl,callback));
        });
    }
    void LoadPictureURL (string url, LoadPictureCallback callback)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadPictureEnumerator(url,callback));

    }


} // end FBSingleton class
```

Comment: Can we download your game somewhere to have a look?

Comment: Sure! The links for the Android and iOS versions are on this page: [link](http://www.ternin.com)